# Got HSEARCH000135: Unable to guess FieldBridge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Hibernate is trying to guess FieldBridge when column is not indexed.

I have entity A with such filed.

```
@Embedded
@AttributeOverrides(@AttributeOverride(name = "value", column = @Column(name = "TYPE")))
private TypeValue type;
```

`TypeValue identificationType` is a `ValueObject`

```
@Embeddable
public class TypeValue {
    private String value;


    public TypeValue () {
    }

    public TypeValue (String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value =  value;
    }
}
```

For some reason I got this error:
HSEARCH000135: Unable to guess FieldBridge for type...

HibernateVersion: 5.6.3.Final